# Python set Union and set Intersection operate differently?

Tags: python, set, union, intersection

I'm doing some set operations in Python, and I noticed something odd..

```
>> set([1,2,3]) | set([2,3,4])
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
>> set().union(*[[1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

That's good, expected behaviour - but with intersection:

```
>> set([1,2,3]) & set([2,3,4])
set([2, 3])
>> set().intersection(*[[1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
set([])
```

Am I losing my mind here? Why isn't set.intersection() operating as I'd expect it to?

How can I do the intersection of many sets as I did with union (assuming the `[[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]` had a whole bunch more lists)? What would the "pythonic" way be?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

When you do `set()` you are creating an empty set.  When you do `set().intersection(...)` you are intersecting this empty set with other stuff.  The intersection of an empty set with any other collection of sets is empty.

If you actually have a list of *sets*, you can get their intersection similar to how you did it.

```
>>> x = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}]
>>> set.intersection(*x)
set([3])
```

You can't do this directly with the way you're doing it, though, because you don't actually have any sets at all in your example with `intersection(*...)`.  You just have a list of *lists*.  You should first convert the elements in your list to sets.  So if you have

```
x = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
```

you should do

```
x = [set(a) for a in x]
```

Answer (score 14):

```
set().intersection(*[[1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
```

is of course empty because you start with the empty set and intersect it with all the others

You can try calling the method on the `class`

```
set.intersection(*[[1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
```

but that won't work because the first argument passed needs to be a set

```
set.intersection({1, 2, 3}, *[[2,3,4], ...])
```

This looks awkward, better if you could use a list of sets in the first place. Especially if they are coming from a generator which makes it difficult to pull off the first item cleanly

```
set.intersection(*[{1,2,3}, {2,3,4}])
```

Otherwise you can just *make* them all into sets

```
set.intersection(*(set(x) for x in [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]))
```

Answer (score 10):

convert the list to set first

```
>>> set.intersection(*[set([1,2,3]), set([2,3,4])])
set([2, 3])
```

For multiple lists you can just use,

```
>>> set.intersection(*[set([1,2,3]), set([2,3,4]), set([5,3,4])])
set([3])
```

Comment: `set.intersection` is different from `set().intersection`

Comment: It does however achieve the output I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

[removed incorrect answer]

As @Anto Vinish suggested you should first convert the lists to sets and then use set.intersection

For example:

```
>>> sets = [set([1, 2, 3]), set([2, 3, 4]), set([3, 4, 5])]
>>> set.intersection(*sets)
set([3])
```

Comment: How would I intersect many sets in a similar manner to how I unioned many?

Comment: @Hypuk If answer is incorrect then you may delete it (if you wants)